# Php Alert doesn't show

Tags: php

good afternoon. I have a Modal Form and the data is send via Ajax. The problem is that I try to know if the data already exist in data base and then get an alert. In my database the data is not repeating, but the alert is not appearing.

Part of Php code:

```
require 'puenteConexion.php';
// ***------------------------------------------------***
$proceso = $_POST['pro']; 
$id = $_POST['id-paciente'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre']; 
$apellido_pat = $_POST['apellido_pat']; 
$apellido_mat = $_POST['apellido_mat']; 
$sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
$nacimiento = $_POST['nacimiento'];

$total = $conexion->query(" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_paciente WHERE nombre='$nombre' and apellido_pat='$apellido_pat' and nacimiento='$nacimiento' ");
$data_exists = ($total->fetchColumn() > 0) ? true : false;  

if($data_exists){
    die('The person exist');
}else{

    //VERIFICANDO EL PROCESO

    switch($proceso){
    case 'Registro':
        $conexion->query("INSERT INTO tbl_paciente (id_paciente, nombre, apellido_pat, apellido_mat, sexo, nacimiento) VALUES (null,'$nombre','$apellido_pat','$apellido_mat','$sexo','$nacimiento')"); 
    break;

    case 'Edicion':
        $conexion->query("UPDATE tbl_paciente SET nombre = '$nombre', apellido_pat = '$apellido_pat', apellido_mat = '$apellido_mat',
     sexo = '$sexo', nacimiento = '$nacimiento' WHERE id_paciente = '$id'");
        break;
    }

}
```

This is the function that return my Form on submit:

```
function agregaRegistro(){
var url = 'modal/php/agrega_paciente.php';
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:url,
    data:$('#formulario').serialize(),
    success: function(){
        if ($('#pro').val() == 'Registro'){
        $('#formulario')[0].reset();
        $('#modal-mensaje').addClass('bien').html('Registro completado con exito').show(200).delay(1600).hide(200);
        $('#pro').val('Registro');

        return false;
        }else{
        $('#modal-mensaje').addClass('bene').html('Edicion completada con exito').show(200).delay(1600).hide(200);

        return false;
        }
    }
});
return false;
};
```

**Sorry, I edited the question, I hope to be more clear.
Thanks for your attention**

Comment: Two ways to go about this, one is to check using ajax and get a response, json preferably, when the response comes and its a certain result, you can alert in your javascript file. Alternatively, you alert in php, something along the lines of echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("blah");</script>'; i don't recommend this approach anyway, could break code, the former is prefered. But i hope ou understand the endgame here

Comment: How are you processing the output of your php script, what does the javascript look like?

Comment: Are you using vanilla js or jquery to run your ajax request...

Comment: do u want to get this `The person exist` in alert?

Comment: @jeroen `echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("blah");</script>';` not broke the code but still alert doesn't appear. May be I don't explain me, but I don't understand why the Alert or Echo doesn't work.

Comment: @devpro Yes, I do.

Comment: You should take a look at the jQuery manual on `$.ajax()`. There you will see that if you use `success: function(data){`, you will have the output of the php script in the `data` variable.

Comment: @jeroen And that is related to the alerts are not displayed?

Comment: Yes, if you don't do anything with the output of the php script, nothing will show.

Comment: one more thing, u also need to use status because how can u check either getting error or success in ajax response. @jeroen sir m i right?

Comment: @devpro I'm not sure what status you mean; as long as the php script does not error out (or send a 4xx or 5xx header...), you will end up in the `success` function. Personally I'd set a status in the php script and send it back as part of a json response. **Edit:** Just noticed your answer, yes, that :-)

Comment: @jeroen: yes, and status will tell everything either dispaly success message or error message in ajax success function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using any response in your ajax request. you need to get response as:

```
success: function(response){
```

Don't know why are you using `die()` here, you can just use `echo` here as:

```
if($data_exists){
    echo 'The person exist';
}else{
    // else part
}
```

But, still how can you check either getting success or error in ajax response. you can use json here like:

```
if($data_exists){
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>0,'message'=>'The person exist'));    // for error 
}else{
    // else part
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>1,'message'=>'Success message')); // for success
}
```

After this, you need to change your ajax as:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:url,
    data:$('#formulario').serialize(),
    dataType: "json",  // will return json response
    success: function(response){
        if(response.status){
            // your success part
        }
        else{
            alert(response.message); // error response in alert
        }
    }
});
```

**Other Improvements:**

*You can use [Prepared Statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for preventing your SQL Statements with SQL Injection.*

Comment: You are The Man. Thank you very much!! The Echo doesn't works, but the method with Ajax alerts it does. I appreciate your knowledge and your time. Thanks and guys thanks too!

Comment: @Emm: glad to help u friend.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any alert in ypur success function.  So the browser obviously won't alert.

I will try an edit:

```
success: function(something){
    if ($('#pro').val() == 'Registro'){
    $('#formulario')[0].reset();
    $('#modal-mensaje').addClass('bien').html('Registro completado con exito').show(200).delay(1600).hide(200);
    $('#pro').val('Registro');

    alert (something);

    return false;
    }else{
    $('#modal-mensaje').addClass('bene').html('Edicion completada con exito').show(200).delay(1600).hide(200);

    return false;
    }
```

Comment: this alert works whether or not there data in the database.